# How can I get a video direct download link from Google Drive

Tags: html, video, google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to know how I can generate the direct download link of a Google Drive video to use it in a < video > tag. Here is an example:

Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlouiWkFFFY-EifBvTROUu6FQbmmZDiJ/view
Link directo: https://doc-0g-8c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/p22vt9slaonv5s18tm3a1jpe77d8lu5p/s1m3t0dva8abf90eubu4n3fumjedpmmk/1604628150000/06703729259022707558/01934340001261439815/1FlouiWkFFFY-EifBvTROUu6FQbmmZDiJ?e=download&authuser=0&nonce=d0jh448t78up6&user=01934340001261439815&hash=2vgeqfmorr1bk3lrmp6quc2mdrd8h47p

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `webContentLink` field from the Drive API.

> `webContentLink` > A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Google Drive.

Therefore, you will have to make the following request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?fields=webContentLink
```

Where `fileId` is the id of the video you are mentioning.

Depending on your exact needs, you might also want to take a look at the `webViewLink` parameter.

#### Reference

- [Files Resource Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files);
- [Files:get Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).